# WPF DataBinding Combobox binding doesn't always happen

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, combobox

I have a `DataGrid` in a `UserConrtol` that has 5 cols - 1 header (read only), 3 text boxes & 1 combo box. I have the `DataGrid` bound to a `ObservableCollection`. The only problem I face is :
The property bind of `ComboBox` "Unit" doesn't get updated if I change ONLY the `ComboBox`of the row. If I change the value of other col & of `ComboBox`too, then it gets updated.
BUT, if I change only the `ComboBox`item from list and come out of the grid/row, the `ComboBox` property doesn't get updated. I tried different ways, but unable to find the cause of the above. The code is :

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="133" Name="dgvData" Width="550" BorderBrush="#FFB7B39D" 
                  Background="LightYellow" RowBackground="LightGray" AlternatingRowBackground="#FFFFFFF5" BorderThickness="10" 
                  CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                  FontSize="13" CanUserAddRows="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Step3ModelList, Mode=TwoWay}">              
     <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="" Binding="{Binding SqueezeHeader, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" MinWidth="110" IsReadOnly="True"/>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Preflush" Binding="{Binding Preflush, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" MinWidth="110"/>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Main Injection" Binding="{Binding MainInjection, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" MinWidth="110"/>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Overflush" Binding="{Binding Overflush, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" MinWidth="110"/>
         <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="reasonColumn" Header="Unit" Width="Auto" >
               <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate>
                       <!-- ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.UnitItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" SelectedValue="{Binding Unit, Mode=TwoWay}" Text="Unit" /  -->

                      <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.UnitItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" SelectedValue="{Binding Unit, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" >
                      </ComboBox>
                  </DataTemplate>
             </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>

    <DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
           <validator:SqueezeEntryValidation ValidationStep="UpdatedValue" />
    </DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
    <DataGrid.RowValidationErrorTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="0,-2,0,-2" ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                                                FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}},
                                                            Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}">
                <Ellipse StrokeThickness="0" Fill="Red" Width="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" Height="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" />
                <TextBlock Text="!" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  />
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowValidationErrorTemplate>

 </DataGrid>
```

Unit property of the object that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`

```
    public string Unit
    {
        get { return unit; }
        set
        {
            if (unit != value)
            {
                unit = value;
                Changed("Unit");
            }
        }
    }
```

Validaion Rule

```
public class SqueezeEntryValidation : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        Step3Model model = (value as BindingGroup).Items[0] as Step3Model;

        if (model.SqueezeHeader == null || model.SqueezeHeader == string.Empty)
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Squeeze Header can not be empty");
        if (model.Preflush < 0)
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Preflush can not be negative");
        if (model.Overflush < 0)
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Overflush can not be negative");
        if (model.MainInjection < 0)
            return new ValidationResult(false, "MainInjection can not be negative");

        return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
    }
}
```

I tried calling `Validate` on `ComboBox` also, so that would update the results, but `Validate` is never called when `ComboBox` value is changed.

How do I make sure, that the Unit property of `ComboBox` is always updated - if any `TextBox` is updated or not. User clicks `Tab` or loses focus in any way or whatever the user does, if the value is changed, then it got to get updated.

Can anyone please help me with this. What am I missing or getting wrong ?

Comment: Try adding `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` to your SelectedValue-binding.

Comment: that did the work. I had tried UpdateSourceTrigger with Mode=TwoWay, that didn't worked. Now without Mode I tried adding UpdateSourceTrigger and it works. Ohhh. Thanks a lot, Florian.

Comment: Glad I could help, I post this as answer, so you can mark this one as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` to your SelectedValue-binding.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.UnitItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" SelectedValue="{Binding Unit, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
</ComboBox>
```